# I am using IWebHostEnvironment to get the WebRootPath and download a PDF but in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I run the app, I get an error in the browser

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: C:\Users\windows\Desktop\streetcode\WebApplication4\wwwroot\pdfs\sample.pdf.

What I see is that I always get a `.` at the end of the path - any help?

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return File($"{_env.WebRootPath}\\pdfs\\sample.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: The dot denotes the end of the exception message. In what web server does this code run, under which user? Does the file actually exist under that path, what happens if you paste it in your Windows Explorer's address bar?

Comment: yes I have my sample.pdf inside the pdfs folder , when I paste it on the browser didn't work I look for the file and copy the path and pase it again and it work , what I notice is that the path is build with this characters / and as you see on the example they are like this \

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it work change the char `\` to `/`

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    var webPath = _env.WebRootPath;
    var path = Path.Combine(webPath, "\\pdfs\\sample.pdf");

    path = path.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, 
    Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);

    return File(path, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: The OP's code *already has* the forward slash in `application/pdf` and back-slashes in `\\pdfs\\sample.pdf` ... **exactly** as your code does.